# Couldn't install nvidia geforce driver after installing win 8 pro in dell 5421

Tags: windows-8, dell-inspiron, nvidia-geforce

When i try to install nvidia geforce driver in my laptop (after installing windows 8) it shows no compatible hardware found and stops installation process. Nvidia auto detect also doesn't shows even after installing the java support for it.

Comment: Are you sure you have Nvidia hardware?

Comment: Ya Ramhound . I had used it before. It didn't worked as i rebooted my os.